# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'node' Lavalink

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a music bot in python, and I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'node'
```

I suspect that this part of the code is causing this problem:

```py
    @cog_ext.cog_slash(name="play", guild_ids=guild_ids, description="Play song")
    async def play(self, ctx, *, query: str):
        """ Searches and plays a song from a given query. """
        # Get the player for this guild from cache.
        player = self.bot.lavalink.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)
        # Remove leading and trailing <>. <> may be used to suppress embedding links in Discord.
        query = query.strip('<>')

        # Check if the user input might be a URL. If it isn't, we can Lavalink do a YouTube search for it instead.
        # SoundCloud searching is possible by prefixing "scsearch:" instead.
        if not url_rx.match(query):
            query = f'ytsearch:{query}'

        # Get the results for the query from Lavalink.
        results = await player.node.get_tracks(query)

        # Results could be None if Lavalink returns an invalid response (non-JSON/non-200 (OK)).
        # ALternatively, resullts['tracks'] could be an empty array if the query yielded no tracks.
        if not results or not results['tracks']:
            return await ctx.send('Nothing found!')
```

Let me know if anyone needs more code, I don't want to spam all the code if it is not needed

Comment: It seems that `self.bot.lavalink.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)` returns None. Have you tried to find out what that function expects/in what situation it returns None?

Comment: @jrbergen Hi, for some reason, the same function written the exact same way works with discord.py normal commands but not with discord slash commands, i don't understand why and since slash commands are relatively new there is no information in lavalinks docs in using it with slash commands

Comment: Ah right. I'm sorry I can't help you with that. Maybe someone else knows.